# (Only in IE) SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. main.js, line 152 character 28

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

After going through several stackoverflow posts regarding this error and none of them actually apply to my case, I am getting this error on a line in my js file in developer tools while debugging:-

```
var el = $("#" + tagName);
 el.val(el.html(value).text()); //this is the one where debugger points to
```

This is the relevant code in js file:-

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "cgi-bin/system_status.cgi?tokn="+sessnID+",active="+tickle_activity+",id="+page_id+",sub="+sub_id+",tab="+tab_id,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            errorCnt = 0;
            $(xml).find('response').children().each(function () {
                if (this.nodeName === "user_info") {
                    parseUserInfo(this);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).children().each(function () {
                        var tagName = this.tagName;
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        /* If this is a time block then do some translation */
                        if (tagName === "time") {
                            if (showTimeValues != undefined) { showTimeValues(this); }
                        }
                        else if (tagName === "satellite") {
                            if (parseSatDataXml != undefined) { parseSatDataXml(xml); }
                        }
                        else if (tagName === "ntpstatus") {
                            if (parseNtpDataXml != undefined) { parseNtpDataXml(xml); }
                        }
                        else if (tagName === "alarms") {
                            if (parseAlmDataXml != undefined) { parseAlmDataXml(xml); }
                        }
                        else if (tagName === "alarmSettings") {
                            if (parseAlmSettingDataXml != undefined) { parseAlmSettingDataXml(xml); }
                        }
                        else if (tagName === "status") {
                            setStatusTextColor(value);
                            setStatusButton(value);
                            $("#" + tagName).val(value);
                        }
                        else {
                           var el = $("#" + tagName);
                           el.val(el.html(value).text());//error thrown

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Only in IE im having this issue, in all other browsers it works fine and i dont observe anything else other than that error in the debugging tools. I am using IE9 and latest jquery version 1.12.1

Comment: IE what? There have been many versions of IE. What version of jQuery? What operating system?

Comment: Do you have a valid element in $("#" + tagName) ? Sounds like IE is complaining because you dont.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I am using IE9 and latest version of jquery 1.12.1 .

Comment: IE9's pretty old. I don't have access to it. As always, please provide a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet alright will keep this in mind from next time

Comment: No, from _this_ time!

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I would very much appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: @David: I am tried console.log(el.val(el.html(value).text())) and see what it produces. In chrome it is able to show me as an object but in IE it just crashes at that point

Comment: And I told you that in order to get help you need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may go ahead and do that now.

Comment: @RajatBansal you can edit your post using the little "edit" link underneath it.

Comment: @ratchetfreak : I did. I have now included ie version and jquery version.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even though I was using IE9 in my developer tools there was an option which said Browser Mode: and it was set to IE7 standards. That is why I was getting this error. The moment i switched to IE9 standards (not the compatibility mdoe option). It all works as expected. If you are new to web development like me you might encounter this issue(not being aware that there are browser modes) as well.
So in summary,
`In debugger tools (F12) -> Click on browser mode and choose IE9`.

Dont choose the compatibility option.